# Get value of multiple choices checkboxes Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the onsubmit event on a form to verify it before it is sent. I'm having issues getting the value of checkboxes that allows multiple choice.

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="question5[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="question5[]" value="2" />
```

Javascript:

```
var form = document.forms['questionnaire'];
var q5 = form.elements["question5"].value;
```

When I try to get the value of this question I'm not able to retrieve it the same way I did for the other fields. I'm wondering what is the correct way to get the value of those checkboxes since I can't retrieve it like a radio or text input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the field is `question5[]` not `question5` and since you have multiple of them, you will get a NodeList (which is like an Array) back, not a single Element.

Comment: I tried `var q5 = form.elements["question5"][0].value;` and `var q5 = form.elements["question5[]"].value;` but I didn't try to combine those. It works now.